# How do I extract a subset of a time series according to a custom interval using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, subset, forex

I have a dataset of forex prices for every minute, 24 hours a day, every day, for one month. However, the forex market is only actually open from 17:00 on Sunday to 16:00 on Friday, the data in between these times is simply padded with the last recorded value on Friday evening. I am trying to remove this padding and be left with market-open data only.

I have gone down dozens of dead ends and have completely lost the wood for the trees.

It is beautifully simple to return a subset of the data according to a specified time-frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(tickdatafile,index_col='dtime',parse_dates=True)

# Return all rows for times between 12:00 and 16:00
df = df.between_time('12:00','16:00')
```

The first two lines create a dataframe from a csv file, allocate the 'dtime' column as the index and parse it as a datetime object.
The third line returns all rows between 12:00 and 16:00 regardless of what day it is.

A simple one line solution would look like (pseudocode):

```
df = df.between_customTimeRange('Sun 17:00','Fri 16:00')
```

but obviously, this doesn't work.

Is there something simple that I have completely overlooked?

**Edit:**
I've combined EKomarov and Alexander's answers into the following solution start to finish:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(tickdatafile,index_col='dtime',parse_dates=True)

mask = df[ ( (   df.index.weekday == 6 ) & ( df.index.hour < 17 ) )# Sunday pre 17:00
         |   (   df.index.weekday == 5 )                           # All of Saturday
         | ( (   df.index.weekday == 4 )                           # Friday
           &                         (     ( df.index.hour >= 16 ) # Friday 16.00 onwards
                                     &  ~( ( df.index.hour == 16 )
                                         & ( df.index.minute == 0 )# Exclude 16.00 itself
                                         )
                                     )
           )
         ]

df = df[~df.index.isin(mask.index)] # return all data not in mask
df.to_csv(tradingdaysonly)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the same approach as @EKomarov, but treated time differently.  Stamps is your pd.Timestamp index.  First create the mask of dates/times you don't want, and then invert it.  Note that dayofweek is indexed with Monday=0 and Sunday=6.

```
mask = stamps[((stamps.dayofweek == 6) & (stamps.hour < 17))  # Sunday before 17:00
              | (stamps.dayofweek == 5)   # All of Saturday
              | ((stamps.dayofweek == 4)  # Friday after 16:00
                 & (stamps.hour >= 16) 
                 & ~((stamps.hour == 16) & (stamps.minute == 0)))]  # Exclude 16:00

stamps[~stamps.isin(mask)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution.

I'd reduce the problem to disposing of not needed timestamps. Those, "wrong" timestamps, are between Fri-16:00 and Sun-17:00.

Say you have

```
data = pd.Series( np.random.randn(100), index = pd.date_range('2015-04-01', periods = 100, freq = '6h') )
```

Lets find "wrong" timestamps:

```
    paddedTimestamps = ( ( (data.index.dayofweek == 4) & (data.index.time > datetime.time(16,0)) ) | 
                           (data.index.dayofweek == 5) | 
                         ( (data.index.dayofweek == 6) & (data.index.time < datetime.time(17,0)) ) )
```

Now paddedTimestamps contains True for each integer location where timestamp is "wrong", so we invert it and query for the data:

```
nonPaddedData = data[~paddedTimestamps]
```